# Delivering Java se project to complete non technical customers

Tags: java

Suppose I have a phone book java desktop application which  uses peoples name,address,phone numbers etc stored in a database.database server used is mysql and persistence using hibernate framework.Then how am i suppose to deliver this application to so called customer who has no at all programming knowlewdge??

PS:i have used eclipse as my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the prerequisites, create needed batch/bash file for start and installation.
Put every thing together with the use of an installer like [innosetup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php)
That's the way i do it...